# Inyectar EJB en controlador

Tags: java, java-ee, servlets, ejb, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Estoy con una aplicación JEE a base de Servlets y EJB 3.1.
Quiero inyectar los EJB mediante anotación. Desde el propio Servlet puedo hacero, pero si lo hago a través de otra clase (un Controlador) no lo inyecta. 
Me explico con el ejemplo:

Tengo el siguiente EJB

```
@Local
public interface StackOverflowSession {
    String formularPregunta(String idPregunta);
}

@Stateless
public class StackOverflowSessionBean extends BaseSession implements StackOverflowSession {
        ...
}
```

Y a continuación el Servlet, desde el cual, mediante la anotación `@EJB` me lo inyecta sin problema y puedo acceder a sus métodos:

```
public class StackOverflowServlet extends ServletBase<Pregunta> {
    @EJB
    StackOverflowSession stackOverflowSession;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String idPregunta = request.getParameter("idPregunta");
    String pregunta = stackOverflowSession.formularPregunta(idPregunta);
    } 
}
```

Sin embargo, si en lugar de realizarlo directamente, hago una clase intermedia *Controller* que haga esta tarea:

```
public class StackOverflowController {
    @EJB
    StackOverflowSession stackOverflowSession;

    public String formularPregunta(final String idPregunta) {
          return stackOverflowSession.formularPregunta(idPregunta);
    }
}
```

Y desde el Servlet la utilizo:

```
public class StackOverflowServlet extends ServletBase<Pregunta> {

    StackOverflowController stackOverflowController;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
          super.init();
          stackOverflowController = new StackOverflowController();
    }

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
           String idPregunta = request.getParameter("idPregunta");
           String pregunta = stackOverFlowController.formularPregunta(idPregunta);
    }

}
```

De esta forma, `stackOverflowSession` en `StackOverflowController` no está inicializado, y da su correspondiente `NullPointer`.

¿Alguien me podría explicar porqué este comportamiento?

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Hola al realizar el new StackOverflowController(), el cliclo de vida del bean no es gestionado por el contendor, por eso motivo  @EJB  StackOverflowSession stackOverflowSession; no es instanciado.

Comment: Me imaginaba que iban por ahí los tiros. Entonces, ¿debería inyectar stackOverflowController en el servelt? ¿es posible hacerlo?

Comment: Debería ser posible con EJB y CDI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los objetos gestionados (*managed beans*) los inyecta el contenedor (CDI, JSF) **cuando es el contenedor el que crea los objetos**.

Aquí es tú código el que crea una instancia de `StackOverflowController`

> stackOverflowController = new StackOverflowController();

así que no te inyecta nada.

Tienes que hacer que `StackOverflowController` sea un objeto gestionado, con la anotación adecuada al framework que uses, y hacer que se inyecte en el `servlet` , p.ej.

```
@Inject
private StackOverflowController stackOverflowController;
```

Comment: Estoy usando JEE con jboss 6.2. Utilizando @Inject en stackOverflowController; no consigo inyectarla en el servlet

Comment: A ver, no he dado todos los detalles sobre como usar CDI; por ejemplo necesitarás anotar `StackOverflowController` (lo más normal es que con `@Default`, y quizás una anotación de *scope*, y añadir un `META-INF/beans.xml`). Más información sobre CDI aquí: https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/cdi-conceptos-avanzados/ y por todas partes hay tutoriales.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora estoy indicandole scope, la anotación @Default  y añadiendole beans.xml, el arranque de jboss indica: ' JBAS016060: No se pudo resolver bean CDI para punto de inyeccion com.stackoverflow.controller.StackOverflowController com.stackoverflow.servlet.StackOverflowServlet.stackOverflowController con calificadores []'. Según manuales que he visto parece que con eso ya debería ser suficiente.

Comment: Vale, he detectado que el beans.xml lo tengo que añadir tanto en el web-inf como en meta-inf